# JSON schema validator in Scala

Tags: json, scala, validation, jsonschema

I need to validate the schema of certain JSON input I receive. I am not clear about how to go about the whole thing. But this is what I have gathered so far :

1. I need to prepare a schema for all sorts of input using something like  http://json-schema.org/implementations.html
2. Then I need a validator like https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator
3. I need to give the json input to and the schema to the validator and get the result.

However my question is that I need to use a jar which I can import and use of the json-schema-validator https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator . Also I am not clear on how to use it. I don't know the format it accepts , the classes and methods needed etc.

4. How good the validator's support is for Scala?

Comment: for Scala - try: https://github.com/nparry/orderly4jvm , there is examples how to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go through the pain of manually collecting the jars of json schema validator (done that, not fun). It is better use a tool for that (like maven, sbt, gradle or ivy).
In case you want to use it in an OSGi environment, you might need to use a [different (probably not up-to-date) version](https://github.com/boly38/json-schema-validator-bundle).

Usage:

```
val factory: JsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getDefault
val validator: JsonValidator = factory.getValidator
val schemaJson: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode = yourJsonSchemaInJackson2Format
val report: ProcessingReport = validator.validate(schemaJson, yourJsonInJackson2Format)
//check your report.
```

PS.: In case you want to collect the dependencies manually, you can go through the dependencies transitively starting on [this page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.2.6).

Comment: what is Jackson2Format?

Comment: Plain JSON read to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`.

Comment: And how exactly do I bind a plan json to a Jnode?

Comment: `mapper.readTree(...)` see: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#3-minute-tutorial-generic-collections-tree-model

Comment: Could you please help my friend with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535691/comparing-the-json-data-types-at-runtime-using-jackson-and-scala?noredirect=1#comment124687201_70535691

Answer (score 1):

There is [Orderly](http://github.com/nparry/orderly4jvm), `liftweb-json`-based JSON validator implementation for Scala:

```
import com.nparry.orderly._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._

val orderly = Orderly("integer {0,100};")

val noProblems = orderly.validate(JInt(50))
val notAllowed = orderly.validate(JInt(200))
```

Use [`net.liftweb.json.parse(s: String): JValue`](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/) to obtain JValue from String.

Comment: How to validate JSon against JSon-schema with Orderly?

Comment: @AlexanderMyltsev you can't, but [Orderly](http://orderly-json.org/)-schema itself  would be a good alternative. You can export Orderly as Json-schema and vice versa: http://orderly-json.org/tryit

Comment: @dk, Orderly seems really cool: short and clean. But unfortunately it is dead, and seems like not supporting recent version of json-schema.

Comment: @AlexanderMyltsev last release from scala-repo was 2 monthes before my answer, last github update - 3 monthes ago. I wouldn't say that JSON-schema is too much alive (in comparision with xsd/relax-ng) and also there is no scala-oriented solutions for validators. Talking about modern JSONSchema, orderly converts fine to draft v4, maybe not vice-versa. Anyway, it's still good alternative for simple validations, regardless of being 6-years old.

Comment: Yes, Orderly4jvm seems alive. Why are you saying that JSON Schema is not alive?

Comment: @AlexanderMyltsev I'm not, where did I say that??! I'm saying that imho it's evolving slowly and definetly still a draft.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that orderly4jvm does not support the latest JSON Schema version 4, which causes problems if you want to use it to generate the JSON schema.