# Comparing the json data types at runtime using Jackson and Scala

Tags: scala, jackson, user-defined-functions, jackson-databind

I have an incoming `JSON` data that looks like below:

```
{"id":"1000","premium":29999,"eventTime":"2021-12-22 00:00:00"}
```

Now, I have created a class that will accept this record and will check whether the data type of the incoming record is according to the data types defined in the `case class`. However, when I am calling the method it is always calling the `Failure` part of the match case.

```
    case class Premium(id: String, premium: Long, eventTime: String)
    
    class Splitter extends ProcessFunction[String, Premium] {
      val outputTag = new OutputTag[String]("failed")
    
      def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Either[String, T] = {
        Try {
          println("inside")
          lazy val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
          mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
          mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
          mapper.readValue[T](json)
        } match {
          case Success(x) => {
            Right(x)
          }
          case Failure(err) => {
            Left(json)
          }
        }
      }
override def processElement(i: String, context: ProcessFunction[String, Premium]#Context, collector: Collector[Premium]): Unit = {
    fromJson(i) match {
      case Right(data) => {
        collector.collect(data)
        println("Good Records: " + data)
      }
      case Left(json) => {
        context.output(outputTag, json)
        println("Bad Records: " + json)
      }
    }
  }
    }
```

Based on the sample record above, it should pass the `Success` value but no matter what I pass, it always enters the `Failure` part. What else is missing?

I am using `Scala 2.11.12` and I tried examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270621/using-jackson-to-de-serialize-a-scala-case-class) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966743/small-example-of-jackson-scala-module) link but no luck.

Comment: Seems to be working [fine](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tPkvOQHiRcaaaJ6jBGrkTQ). What error are you getting.

Comment: Just a sec check my other method in the code. There I am passing the value from the `Failure` part and printing it and when I am passing the data it is always printing the `Failure` part. Why is it so? Or there is some gap in my understanding?

Comment: If I pass this data `"{\n  \"id\":\"asd\",\n  \"premium\":\"123\",\n  \"eventTime\":\"2021-20-12 00:00:00\"\n}"` it is giving me as the `Success` part but it should have been failed since the second attribute is of `String` type and not `Long`

Comment: `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS)`

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: Somewhere around `mapper.configure`

Comment: I added below it and also checked without `configure` but still the same

Comment: It is to prevent handling of number strings as [numbers](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pjaQxBB8SAetVoiN1fQsXA)

Comment: Now, if I pass `"{\"id\":1000,\"premium\":29999,\"eventTime\":\"2021-12-22 00:00:00\"}"` it gives me as the correct record instead of bad record because the first attribute is of Int type and not String. So,here the expected result is Bad record

Comment: Any suggestions pls?

Comment: After a lot of research, I found out that this Parser doesn't have a strict mode within it so what is happening is if I pass some string value for the first attribute, still it is giving me a good record instead of a bad one. Any other suggestions pls?